# Iterating form over rows and columns at once on DataFrame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set, say df, which has following information. Basically i want iterate over columns & create new columns

```
df

ID Day1 Day2....Day10  

1  High  Low  

2  Medium High  

3  Low    Medium  

4  Low    Low  

5  High   High  

.   .      .  
.   .      .  
.   .      .
```

Now, i want the output below: For each Day1 to Day10, i would like to create new columns from
Tag1 to Tag10.

```
ID Day1 Day2....Day10 Tag1 Tag2.......Tag10  

1  High  Low........  3     1        

2  Medium High        2     3

3  Low    Medium      1     2

4  Low    Low         1     1

5  High   Medium      3     2

.   .      .          .     .  
.   .      .          .     .
.   .      .          .     .
```

I have tried blow code, but it seems not working

```
df1=df.reindex(columns=[*df.columns.tolist(),'Tag1','Tag2','Tag3','Tag4','Tag5','Tag6','Tag7','Tag8','Tag9','Tag10'],fill_value='NA')

days=['Tag1','Tag2','Tag3','Tag4','Tag5','Tag6','Tag7','Tag8','Tag9','Tag10']

for j in days:
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df[i]=='High':
            df[i,j]=1
        else:
            df[i,j]=0
    j+=1
```

Comment: What are the rules to fill `Tag1` to `Tag10` columns?

Comment: If it is High then 3, if Medium then 2 and if Low then value should be 1

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for `Day` columns, then [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), change columns names and append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
d = {"Low": 1, "Medium": 2, "High": 3}
f = lambda x: x.replace('Day','Tag')
df = df.join(df.filter(like='Day').replace(d).rename(columns=f))
print (df)
   ID    Day1    Day2  Tag1  Tag2
0   1    High     Low     3     1
1   2  Medium    High     2     3
2   3     Low  Medium     1     2
3   4     Low     Low     1     1
4   5    High    High     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to prepare a mapping dictionary which contains key-value pairs where the keys are the entries in the `Day` column and values are the one which you want to assign the corresponding entries in Tag column. Then you can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function to map each entry in the given `Day` col to corresponding value in the dictionary and then assign this to the new `Tag` column.

**Use this:**

```
import re

mapping = {"High": 3, "Medium": 2, "Low": 1}
for col in df.columns:
    mobj = re.search(r"Day(\d+)", col)
    if mobj:
        df[ f"Tag{mobj.group(1)}"] = df[col].map(mapping) #--> map the values in dictionary

print(df)
```

**Sample Result:**

```
   ID    Day1    Day2  Tag1  Tag2
0   1    High     Low     3     1
1   2  Medium    High     2     3
2   3     Low  Medium     1     2
3   4     Low     Low     1     1
4   5    High    High     3     3
```